# Google Maps v2 zoom to specific marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have a search AutoComplete in my map and display the title from my database. Can it be possible to put zoom functionality to that specific marker? I'm using google maps api v2.

[image: map search]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at these code snippets:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

This should be what you're looking for:

```
GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot about this. >.< Thanks! :)